# Installing kubernetes cluster on master node

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to container worrld and trying to setup a kubernetes cluster locally in two linux VMs. During the cluster initialization it got stuck at

> [apiclient] Created API client, waiting for the control plane to
>   become ready

I have followed the pre-flight check steps,

```
[root@lm--kube-glusterfs--central ~]# kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters.
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.6.0
[init] Using Authorization mode: RBAC
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] WARNING: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[certificates] Generated CA certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated API server certificate and key.
[certificates] API Server serving cert is signed for DNS names [lm--kube-glusterfs--central kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.99.7.215]
[certificates] Generated API server kubelet client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated service account token signing key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy CA certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
[apiclient] Created API client, waiting for the control plane to become ready
```

**OS** : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)

**Kuberneter version :**

kubeadm-1.6.0-0.x86_64.rpm

kubectl-1.6.0-0.x86_64.rpm

kubelet-1.6.0-0.x86_64.rpm

kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64.rpm

cri-tools-1.12.0-0.x86_64.rpm

How to debug the issue or is there any version mismatch of kube versions. Same was working before when i use google.cloud.repo to install `yum -y install kubelet kubeadm kubectl` .

I couldnot use repo due to some firewall issues. Hence using the rpms to install.

After executing the following command,**journalctl -xeu kubelet**

```
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28749]: W0702 09:45:09.841246   28749 kubelet_network.go:70] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28749]: I0702 09:45:09.841304   28749 kubelet.go:494] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28749]: W0702 09:45:09.845626   28749 cni.go:157] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28749]: I0702 09:45:09.857969   28749 docker_service.go:187] Docker cri networking managed by kubernetes.io/no-op
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28749]: error: failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "cgroupfs
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Jul 02 09:45:09 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes Kubelet Server.
-- Subject: Unit kubelet.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit kubelet.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: Starting Kubernetes Kubelet Server...
-- Subject: Unit kubelet.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit kubelet.service has begun starting up.
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.251465   28772 feature_gate.go:144] feature gates: map[]
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: W0702 09:45:20.251889   28772 server.go:469] No API client: no api servers specified
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.252009   28772 docker.go:364] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.252049   28772 docker.go:384] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: W0702 09:45:20.259436   28772 cni.go:157] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.275674   28772 manager.go:143] cAdvisor running in container: "/system.slice"
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: W0702 09:45:20.317509   28772 manager.go:151] unable to connect to Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial r
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.328881   28772 fs.go:117] Filesystem partitions: map[/dev/vda2:{mountpoint:/ major:253 mino
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.335711   28772 manager.go:198] Machine: {NumCores:8 CpuFrequency:2095078 MemoryCapacity:337
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: [7] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:4194304 Type:Unifie
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.338001   28772 manager.go:204] Version: {KernelVersion:3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 Container
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: W0702 09:45:20.338967   28772 server.go:350] No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server.
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.338980   28772 server.go:509] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specifie
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.342041   28772 container_manager_linux.go:245] container manager verified user specified cg
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.342071   28772 container_manager_linux.go:250] Creating Container Manager object based on N
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: W0702 09:45:20.346505   28772 kubelet_network.go:70] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.346571   28772 kubelet.go:494] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: W0702 09:45:20.351473   28772 cni.go:157] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: I0702 09:45:20.363583   28772 docker_service.go:187] Docker cri networking managed by kubernetes.io/no-op
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central kubelet[28772]: error: failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "cgroupfs
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Jul 02 09:45:20 lm--son-config-cn--central systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Related to [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43805)

There are a few fixes shown there , all you need is to change the cgroup driver to **systemd**